# AFNetworking simple GET request

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I'm trying to send a simple GET request using AFNetworking, but the completion handler is not being called. Here is my code:

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
[client getPath:@"/" 
     parameters:nil
        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                    NSLog(@"Success");
                }
        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                    NSLog(@"Failure");
                }];
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** The NSURLConnectionDelegate completion method is being called within AFNetworking, just not passed on to the completion blocks.

Comment: Show the setup/config of `[LKOMSClient sharedClient]`

Comment: And you debugged to check that the client is created, the URL is valid?

Comment: @Wain The NSURLConnectionDelegate calls the connection finished method within AFNetworking - just the completion block isn't being called.

Comment: When debugging specific behavior, you have to be really specific about exactly what code you're using. Talking about behavior in the abstract isn't going to help anyone figure out what's going on. What are the URLs? What are the specific callback functions? What's your network environment? What version of AFNetworking are you using? Stuff like that.

Comment: @mattt: I've tried it with `http://google.com/` as the URL. Those callback functions are good enough right now, because I just want to see if they get called. I am 3 feet from a router so my internet connection is good. I am using the latest version of AFNetworking, 1.3.1.

Comment: Just updated the example to something simpler that I tried with the same result

Comment: @mattt: Are the completion blocks called on the main thread?

Comment: @LennyK Yes, [as per the documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperation.html#//api/name/successCallbackQueue), callbacks are run on the main thread by default.

Comment: @LennyK Did you solve your problem? I am with the same issue here, tried the same code and my success/failure blocks are never called. I'm using AFNetworking 1.3.1

Comment: @GustavoBarbosa I think it's because the main thread was blocked, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @LennyK Solved here. I was calling this method inside a test suite and I just realized that, when running unit tests, the test runner doesnt wait another threads (the callback blocks) to be executed. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @GustavoBarbosa I was doing the same thing, then I started using dispatch semaphores to make the test wait for the callback to be called. However, the semaphore was blocking the main thread, preventing the callback blocks from being called.